# Finding the limit of a function with factorials

Tags: calculus, factorial

I am trying to take the limit of this sequence and to do so, I must first rewrite the expression to be able to cancel out terms.

For example:

$\require{cancel}$
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\cancel{(2n-1)}\cancel{(2n-2)}\cancel{(2n-3)}\cdots\cancel 3\cdot\cancel2\cdot\cancel1}{(2n+1)(2n)(\cancel{(2n-1)}\cancel{(2n-2)}\cancel{(2n-3)}\cdots\cancel 3\cdot\cancel2\cdot\cancel1}\right)\end{align}

What I understand:

$$(2n-1)! = (2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)\cdots$$

---

What I don't understand:

Where does the $3\cdot2\cdot1$ come from?

Shouldn't the next 3 terms be $(2n-4)(2n-5)(2n-6)$?

---

My reasoning:

\begin{align}(2n-3) - 1  &= (2n-4)\\
(2n-4) - 1 &= (2n-5)\\
(2n-5) - 1 &= (2n-6)\end{align}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The next terms are indeed $(2n-4)(2n-5)(2n-6)$ and so on but the solution has used ... to indicate the terms in between, Recall that $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4... n$ those starting $1,2,3$ are included at the end of the solution

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: When you write $(2n-1)! = (2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)...$ with "..." at the end, do you want to imply that the sequence of factors goes on for infinity?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen intuitively, it goes on until $1$.

Comment: @MrPie Why until $1$? "Intuitively", it could go on until $0$ or beyond that

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen until 1, yes. I don't understand the last three numbers, but I do understand that everything past 2n in the numerator is the same as the denominator and so it can all be canceled out leaving 1 in the numerator and 2n(2n+1) in the denominator. Taking the limit of that comes out to 0.

Comment: The problem with the "and so on" notation is that it does not specify an end. The author wanted to express the ambiguous "and so on" notation by more explicitly expressing that the product is of the numbers $2n-1$ and $2n-2$ and $2n-3$, *and so on* **until** we end with factors $3$ and $2$ and $1$. Strictly speaking, this makes sense at most when $2n-3>3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bear in mind that a factorial eventually has to end. When the author places

$$(2n-1)! = (2n-1)(2n-2)(2n-3)\cdots(3)(2)(1)$$

those "$\cdots$" means "the obvious pattern continues until" ... whatever appears after the dots. The obvious pattern is that of the factorial: $z!$ is the product of all of the positive integers less than or equal to $z$ (if $z$ is itself a positive integer). We could write that as, for instance,

$$z! = z(z-1)(z-2)\cdots(3)(2)(1)$$

This becomes more obvious if you plug in a specific value for $n$ or $z$. Let $n=6$ for instance ($z=11$). Then

$$(2n-1)!=z!=11!=11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

though this is cumbersome to write, so one might instead use

$$11! = 11 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot \cdots \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$

---

This is to be contrasted with the case where you have nothing after the dots, in which "$\cdots$" means "the obvious pattern continues infinitely". For example,

$$1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 8 + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \cdots$$

would be such an "infinite" case. (It is the summation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/2)^n$.) Factorials however have to end.

Think of it like this: if the factorial did not end, you would eventually multiply by $0$, which would mean all factorials would be $0$. Kind of silly, isn't it? That's why the interpretation of what "$\cdots$" represents is important.

Comment: So the "...3*2*1" is just a notation used to show that the pattern continues until 1 is reached?

Comment: @KhrisDavis Exactly that!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way do do math is to never rely on ellipsis (aka. three dots). At best, they lead to ambiguity, e.g., how should the sequence $2,3,5,7,11,\ldots$ be continued? If you think the next term is $13$, [it needn't be so](http://oeis.org/A112088). So intead, we should define factorial for all $n\in\Bbb N_0$ by a nice and unambiguous recursion:
$$ n!:=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n=0\\n\cdot(n-1)!&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
With this,
$$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)\cdot(2n)!}=\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)\cdot(2n)\cdot(2n-1)!}=\frac1{(2n+1)\cdot (2n)} $$
for all integers $n\ge1$.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful

Comment: This is a neat way of thinking about it